# VFP 9.0 how to extract all the table relations from a DBC object

Tags: visual-foxpro

I need to extract all the relationships between Parent/Child tables somehow.  Is there a way to do that using the DBC object?

[image: Reminder of how relations look in the VFP DB Designer]

Answer (score 5):

Sorry guys I forgot it over the years, but after some thinking it came to me...

```
OPEN DATABASE ABC
=ADBOBJECTS(ga_Connections, "CONNECTION")
=ADBOBJECTS(ga_Relations, "RELATION")
=ADBOBJECTS(ga_Views, "VIEW")
=ADBOBJECTS(ga_Tables, "TABLE")
CLOSE DATABASES
```

The global array `ga_Relations` is an N x 5 array with

Parent table, Child table, Parent key, Child key, empty string cell

You can create a cursor and insert the array into it as follows:

```
CREATE CURSOR dbRelat (Parent_Table C(40),Child_Table C(40),Parent_Key C(40),Child_key C(40),Spacer C(1))

TRY 
    INSERT INTO dbRelat FROM ARRAY ga_Relations 
CATCH
    MESSAGEBOX("No Relations in this DataBase!",48,1000)
ENDTRY
```

And of course you can do the same for the TABLES, VIEWS and CONNECTIONS...

Hope it is useful to others...

DK